# Efficient way to create a "rolling window" type grouping in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

Imagine you have an n-dimensional tensor where one of those dimensions corresponds to *time*.

What I'd like to do is: given some integer `window_size`,  I'd like to replace my time dimension with two new dimensions, `[..., n_groups, window_size]`. Where `n_groups` is representative of all posible groupings of size `window_size` across the time dimension. So if we started with a time dimension of size `n_periods`, then `n_groups` should end up being `n_periods - window_size`.

All of this is very easy to accomplish using traditional "pythonic" looping and slicing, such as:

```
stacked = tf.stack([inputs[i:i+window_size] for i in range(len(inputs) - window_size + 1)], axis=0)
```

However, if the time dimension is very long, this produces a staggering number of graph operations. I am wondering if there isn't a built-in TensorFlow function that might help me accomplish this relatively simple task more efficiently...

So common is the idea of "rolling-window grouping" that the Pandas project has a very sophisticated and [sizeable API](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to handle this particular case. I would have thought that TensorFlow would also include such a utility.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the tf documentation about map_fn:

***"map_fn will apply the operations used by fn to each element of elems, resulting in O(elems.shape[0]) total operations. This is somewhat mitigated by the fact that map_fn can process elements in parallel. However, a transform expressed using map_fn is still typically less efficient than an equivalent transform expressed using vectorized operations."***

You can try the following approach, given an input tensor:

```
input_tensor = tf.range([10])

# <tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)>
```

convert into a square matrix:

```
 res = tf.repeat(tf.expand_dims(input_tensor, 0), input_tensor.shape[0], axis = 0)

  # array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>
```

Then apply map_fn over this tensor including in the input a range vector with negative values:

```
elements = tf.range(10, dtype=tf.int32) * -1
w,_ = tf.map_fn(lambda x: (tf.roll(x[0], x[1], axis=0), x[1]), (res, elements), dtype=(tf.int32, tf.int32))
```

This will row(left) the elements as:

```
#<tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 10), dtype=int32, numpy=
#array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
#       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
#       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1],
#       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2],
#       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3],
#       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#       [6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#       [7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
#       [8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
#       [9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)>
```

Finally,  take as much element as you need using tensor slicing like:

```
 window = 8
 tf.slice(w, [0, 0], [(w.shape[0] - window) + 1, window])
```

gives:

```
#<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 8), dtype=int32, numpy=
#array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
#       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
#       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>
```

For a window = 4

```
window = 4
tf.slice(w, [0, 0], [(w.shape[0] - window) + 1, window])
```

gives:

```
#array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
#   [1, 2, 3, 4],
#   [2, 3, 4, 5],
#   [3, 4, 5, 6],
#   [4, 5, 6, 7],
#   [5, 6, 7, 8],
#   [6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>
```

Try to. convert this into a tf graph to see if it has better performance than the normal python loop.